# Custom MasterPage class stops working with Bootstrap 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, bootstrap-5

I have an Asp.net WebForm application and I am using MasterPages. My MasterPage code-behind class inherits from a custom class which inherits from the MasterPage base class. This custom master page class maintains different values including user state and it is used on my master page like this,

```
<% if( UserState.Level == UserLevel.Admin)
{ %>
    // Load Styles for Admin
    // Load Javascript files for Admin
<% } %>
```

I am using JQuery, Bootstrap 4, and different custom libraries on the master page as well and everything is working absolutely fine.

I now have to upgrade Bootstrap 4 to Bootstrap 5. What I did was to replace the Bootstrap 4 CSS file with Bootstrap 5 and also replaced the Bootstrap 4 js bundle file with Bootstrap 5. Suddenly I now see a blank page. There are no javascript errors or warnings.

I have inspected and investigate the DOM and it seems that the parent css selector which is displayed and hide according to UserState is not working and it remains hidden. The custom MasterPage class is not working on the MyMasterPage.master file. To me this is pretty strange because as soon as I downgrade to Bootstrap 4, everything starts to work fine but doesn't work with Bootstrap 5.

Has anyone else experienced the same issue?

I am using Html5 doctype.

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html lang="en">
```

I have also updated all the css helpers which are changed in Bootstrap 5 like ml-1 to ms-1 etc

Answer (score 0):

The if statetment has nothing to do with with bootstrap version, if user level is "Admin" the condiition would be true even if you are using bootstrap 4 or 5.

Try to clear browser cache. Some links that explain how to do that for some browsers are below:

1. [Chrome](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)
2. [Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-clear-firefox-cache)
3. [Safari](https://clear-my-cache.com/en/apple-mac-os/safari.html)

More information about bundles in ASP.NET could be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification).